# Websphere error - SRVE0133E - java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 2

Tags: websphere

We see the below errors in the System out logs. Could some one please help me understand what could have caused this?

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest parseParameters SRVE0133E: An error occurred while parsing parameters. {0}
                                 java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 2  A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:473)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.read(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:217)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.fillABuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:4171)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readSingleBlock(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3403)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readBodyBuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3509)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.getRequestBodyBuffer(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:1782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.bufferIsGood(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:373)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.read(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.read(HttpInputStream.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.RequestUtils.parsePostData(RequestUtils.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters(SRTServletRequest.java:2051)

Comment: A file or directory in the path name does not exist. Is it the complete error trace.?